# How to make this link to send PUT request.?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This is a helper method to generate a link in the_comments gem. I want to make it put request.

```
def approved_comment
  "<p class='reply'><a href='/comments/#{@comment.id}/approve_comment'>#{ t('the_comments.approve') }</a>" 
end
```

If any one know how to make it PUT request please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a form tag:

```
def approved_comment
  "<p class='reply'><form action='/comments/#{@comment.id}/approve_comment' method='POST'><input type='submit' value='#{ t('the_comments.approve') }'/><input type='hidden' name='_method' value='PUT'/><input name='authenticity_token' value='#{ form_authenticity_token }' type='hidden'/></form></p>" 
end
```

And I would use a path helper instead of `/comments/#{@comment.id}/approve_comment`

UPDATE: authenticity_token is required too